# How to log Catch exception to a text file

Tags: vb.net, try-catch

I have a vb.net program that runs a Try Catch.  What i'd like to have happen, if there is an exception is have it log that exception to a text file.  I have:

```
Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.Message)
                My.Application.Log.WriteException(ex, TraceEventType.Error, "Exception " & "with argument " & "C:\Log.txt" & ".")

            End Try
```

But it's not sending the exception to the logfile.  What am I missing?

Comment: While not an answer to your question, you should look into Elmah for error logging. http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/deployment/deploying-web-site-projects/logging-error-details-with-elmah-vb

Comment: i wouldn't know. i wrote my own logging class. also, you could be missing this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yhx0xwks.aspx

Comment: you probably do not have access to write to `"C:\"` change to a temp folder or a Users folder

Answer (score 3):

Adding a timestamp in the log file

```
    Catch ex As Exception
        IO.File.AppendAllText("C:\Log.txt", String.Format("{0}[{1}]{2}", Environment.NewLine, DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss"), ex.ToString()))
    End Try
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the example here: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dsxzceby(v=vs.90).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dsxzceby%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) might have mislead you a bit. I find it a bit odd.

I think this is probably better:

```
Public Sub SomeMethodWhichMightGenerateException(byval someArg as String)
    Try 
        ' Code that might generate an exception goes here. 
        ' For example: 
        '    Dim x As Object 
        '    MsgBox(x.ToString) 
    Catch ex As Exception
        My.Application.Log.WriteException(ex, _
        TraceEventType.Error, _
        "Exception with argument " & someArg & ".")
    End Try 
End Sub
```

`fileName` is just a random variable in the msdn example and nothing to to do with where the `Exception` is logged...

Look here [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7fx0fexe(v=vs.90).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7fx0fexe%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) to see where `My.Application.Log.WriteException` writes data to.

Alternatively you could do something like this:

```
    Catch ex As Exception
        IO.File.AppendAllText("C:\Log.txt", String.Format("{0}{1}", Environment.NewLine, ex.ToString()))
    End Try
```

As others have said, however, you're probably better off using an existing error logging framework.

Answer (score 2):

Public Function logerrors(ByVal [error] As String)

```
     Dim filename As String = "Log_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy") + ".txt"
    
    Dim filepath As String = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(Convert.ToString("~/ErrorLog/") & filename)

    If File.Exists(filepath) Then
        Using stwriter As New StreamWriter(filepath, True)
            stwriter.WriteLine("-------------------START-------------" + DateTime.Now)
            stwriter.WriteLine(Convert.ToString("Page :"))
            stwriter.WriteLine([error])
            stwriter.WriteLine("-------------------END-------------" + DateTime.Now)
        End Using
    Else
        Dim stwriter As StreamWriter = File.CreateText(filepath)
        stwriter.WriteLine("-------------------START-------------" + DateTime.Now)
        stwriter.WriteLine(Convert.ToString("Page :"))
        stwriter.WriteLine([error])
        stwriter.WriteLine("-------------------END-------------" + DateTime.Now)
        stwriter.Close()
    End If
    Return [error]
End Function
```

Comment: i just create a class so i can call everywhere if any query ask me